# Is it possible to use a universal code to work with all the pages that has a single parameter using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using

```
RewriteRule ^sign_up/([^/]*)$ /sign_up.php?p=$1 [L]
```

The problem with this is for every page I need to write this same code. 
So I thought about using a universal code to work with all the pages that has a single parameter.

Is that possible?

Comment: You mean something like `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)$ /$1.php?p=$2 [L]`?

Comment: Certainly it is possible to use generic patters for rewriting. But we cannot help with that if you don't tell us what logic should be coded. "every page" is pretty vague.

Comment: nope here variable "p" is constant no? so i want to replace that p also.

Comment: k i ll explain my code. http://example.com/page1.php?id=2 this is my first page and the second one is http://example.com/page2.php?name=vicky , see here both pages having only one parameter. is that possible to write a single code for both pages?. something like : RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?$2=$3. im a beginner. dont hv much knowlg abt .htaccess.

Comment: If `id` and `name` are in the original URL, at the same position, yes

Comment: Something like `page1/id/2` and `page2/name/vicky` but rewriting is a bit useless in this case, it doesn't really make the URL prettier or shorter. I'd rather change the PHP code so each page uses the same GET parameter, instead of using id, name, and god knows what in the 3rd page

Comment: You could also use a complex technic like a rewritemap to associate pages to GET parameters so your map will tell page1's parameter is id and page2's is name. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html. But it looks a bit convoluted and hard to maintain.

Comment: Thanks guys ll try this one. big help